# Laravel/PHP - loop through items in a view

Tags: php, laravel, view, foreach, laravel-blade

i have the following html / blade template:

```
        {{--show all projects--}}

        @if(!empty($projects))

        @foreach($projects as $project)
        <div class="slide">
            <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4">
                <li>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <h3 class="thumbTitle">{{$project->title}}</h3>
                        {{--laat maar 1 image zien --}}
                        @if(!empty($project->project_images))


                        {{ HTML::image('useruploadedimages/'.$project->project_images[0]->url) }}


                        @endif

                    </div>

                </li>
        </div>


    @endforeach

    @endif
    </div>
```

what i want is the following: 8 projects displayed within a div with the .slide class, multiple divs with the .slide class for ervery 8 projects: for example i have 25 projects: than i want to have 4 .slide divs 3 with 8 projects and 1 with a single project...

is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) like this:

```
@foreach(array_chunck($projects->toArray(), 8) as $projects)
    <div class="slide">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4">
            @foreach($projects as $project)
                <li>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <h3 class="thumbTitle">{{$project['title']}}</h3>
                        @if(!empty($project['project_images']))
                            {{HTML::image('....)}}
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Notice the array notation `[]` instead of object notation `->`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this peace of code

```
{{--show all projects--}}

@if(!empty($projects))
    $i  =   8;
    @foreach($projects as $project)
        @if($i%8    ==  0)    // checks for multiples if 8 and wraps your content with div and ul
            <div class="slide">
                <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4">
        @endif      
                    <li>
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <h3 class="thumbTitle">{{$project->title}}</h3>
                            {{--laat maar 1 image zien --}}
                            @if(!empty($project->project_images))


                            {{ HTML::image('useruploadedimages/'.$project->project_images[0]->url) }}


                            @endif

                        </div>

                    </li>
        @if($i++%8  ==  0)      // checks for multiples if 8 and increments i value
                </ul>           // ends the ul and div
            </div>
        @endif  


    @endforeach

@endif
</div>
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can close and open a new .slide div for every 8 projects. I supose the `ul` has to restart in every div as well?

```
@if(!empty($projects))
    <div class="slide">
        <ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4">
            @for($i = 0; $i < count($projects); $i++)
                <?php $project = $projects[$i]; ?>

                <li>
                    <div class="thumb">
                        <h3 class="thumbTitle">{{$project->title}}</h3>
                        {{-- only show one image --}}
                        @if(!empty($project->project_images))
                            { HTML::image('useruploadedimages/'.$project->project_images[0]->url) }}
                        @endif

                    </div>

                </li>

                {{-- If there were 8 projects, start a new .slide --}}
                @if ($i % 8 == 7)
                    </ul></div><div class="slide"><ul class="small-block-grid-1 medium-block-grid-3 large-block-grid-4">
                @endif

            @endfor
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```